# Extending the Eclipse PropertiesView with further tabs for existing PropertySources

Tags: eclipse, plugins, view, properties, tabs

After a quite long struggle with the known and unfortunately one of the few help articles about controlling properties, tabbed properties etc. (links below), I have decided to ask for your help.

What I need to do seems not that hard, but, well, I just couldn't bring the pieces together. So the problem is:

I want to extend the existing properties view of Eclipse (PropertySheet) with some further tabs, which will be later on filled with certain information from EMF objects, which in the end implement IAdaptable. So they can be queried for PropertySources and there are already a few tabs, sections extended in the corresponding project in its manifest, which are being successfully gathered from the Selection Listener of the PropertiesView.

Here comes the tricky part: I don't need to extend this project further, by defining further tabbed properties in its manifest. I need to implement a seperate plug-in project, which does this extension job for the other main project. I don't need extra views or so. This existing project provides the property sources and like sad has its own designed tabbed property view via its extensions.

I have actually become quite familiar with the concept of the views and properties, I can build some Property Sources and let the Properties View gather/show/manipulate the properties.

But this idea, letting an external plug-in extend the Properties View with tabs of an another EMF-based plug-in project, just can't get to me. I am really confused and don't know with what to begin with.

I would be unbelievably glad, if you could point me to the right direction.

Thanks a lot!

*Links:

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Properties-View/properties-view.html

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Tabbed-Properties/tabbed_properties_view.html